# EC2 mail via gmail

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I've got a EC2 / centOS vps, it's got postfix / sendmail for pushing out mail.

Now, the domain it self is set up on Google DNS, with it's mail records pointing to gmail servers.  Gmail is used for primary email / smtp.

Back to the EC2, the ec2 does a weekly email... you can see where I'm going with this; Gmail / Yahoo / etc think the EC2 is a spam server, the from / reply to email is the correct domain, but the server's address / ip doesn't match the domain's MX record.

What's the best way to associate this?

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding a second answer based on the comment from my first answer. You can request a Static IP ([Elastic IP](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-EC2/1346)) from Amazon so you keep the same IP address all the time. This will allow you to use your instance for incoming emails (set the MX Record to your IP address). Next, you may need to send a request to Amazon to remove the [SMTP mail sending limit](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request). Finally, you need to tweak your [SPF Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) to confirm the email coming from your IP is actually coming from your domain. Once this is done, you should be ok. I say should... Email is an interesting "problem" to get around... but that *should* work...

Comment: So I should be able to just set up a SPF record pointing back to the server (even though MX is pointing to gmail server) and that way "affirm" that the EC2 is also representing the domain?

Comment: yea. in theory, it should be posible. with an SPF record, you should be able to add multiple locations that will take mail. Make sure you go though the Amazon SMTP limits, use a static IP and set the DNS records correct, or you may be blacklisted...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postfix to deliver your email though Gmail's SMTP server using the tutorial [here](http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/send-mail-postfix-through-gmails-smtp-on-a-ubuntu-lts-server/). Another alternative, since your using EC2, is to use [Amazon's SES service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), which can also be used in [conjunction with Postfix](http://blog.duoconsulting.com/2012/01/30/using-amazons-ses-with-postfix-as-a-smarthost-forwarder/)

Comment: Is there not a way we can mail out from EC2 without SES and somehow set up a mx record to also point to the ec2 server?

Comment: see my second answer with more details.